# Getting the marker in on-click handler: AngularJS + Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to show the infowindow on top of a marker and I am struggling with it.

Currently I have the following HTML:

```
<map data-ng-model="mymap" zoom="4" center="[38.50, -95.00]">
  <marker ng-repeat="item in list" 
  position="[{{item.coordinates}}]" title="{{item.name}}" 
  icon="./images/i.png"
  on-click="onMarkerClicked(mymap, this)" />            

  <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
</map>`
```

Then, in the corresponding controller, I have:

```
$scope.onMarkerClicked = function(mymap, marker, event){

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow("Hi I am the MARKER" + event.target.title);
    infowindow.open( mymap, event.target );
    //infowindow.open( mymap, marker);
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

However, mymap is has the correct value, while event.target does not seem to work, as well as marker (commented in the reported code)

> Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

When using marker, it is undefined.
How can I manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this GitHub where they discuss this issue - https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/95

They then go on to share an example of using ng-repeat with infoWindow - https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/infowindow_compiled.html

Take a look at the source code on that page, I think it will help you

Comment: Thanks, I added the two info-window tags pairs as reported in the last post of the first link you posted. Now I am seeing the info-windows!

Answer (score 0):

You should actually be passing the marker instance as the second parameter to the open call.

See here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: Yes, how do I pass it? I am trying to use event.target, but it doesn't work. I also tried to pass this as parameter, but the same error. How can I pass it from HTML on-click attribute?

Comment: I also tried to pass the marker (updated my posted code) but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the object `this` as an argument and naming that event later? On top of that if you are using Angular why not doing it with `ng-click="onMarkerClicked(myMap, this, event)"`. I have never used Google Maps this way but it seems to me that your parameters somehow are incorrect.

See this simple fiddle to see what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/ozbafyhh/

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this, event)">Click me</button>

function myFunction (x, event){
    alert(x);
    alert(event);
}
```

Comment: ng-click does not get recognized, I get a compile error. I tried to pass this as a parameter and it turns to be undefined.

Comment: i don't have onclick, just on-click (marker specific)

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that you are unable to pass in event as an argument.